# Defining command for partials derivative in xelatex

Tags: macros, fractions

I've been trying to write a command to display a partial derivative with as follow

[image: partial derivative of f by x]

I've written this :

```
\documentclass[11pt, french]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\selectlanguage{french}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esint}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\par}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\par{f}{x}
\end{document}
```

But it doesn't work...

Comment: Unrelated but never use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with xelatex, it removed unicode support forcing 8bit fonts and inncorrect hyphenation

Comment: `\par` is already defined. Use a different name.

Comment: Thank you for you answers! It works! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\par` is a tex primitive that ends a paragraph. You might expect

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \par already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9 ...{\par}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
                                                  
?
```

But actually you get

```
Runaway argument?
{
! Paragraph ended before \new@command was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.9 \newcommand{\par
                    }[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
?
```

Due to the special nature of `\par`.

Simply call the command something else, such as `\pardiff`, and use in math mode:

```
\documentclass[11pt, french]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\selectlanguage{french}
% xetex \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esint}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\pardiff}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
$\pardiff{f}{x}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you answer! It works! :)

Comment: Unfortunately, `\par` is no TeX primitive in new LaTeX. It is a macro which allows hooks. Things are more and more complicated. On the other hand, `\par` is TeX primitive in OpTeX and user can re-define it without any change of basic behavior, because OpTeX uses `\_par` internally. All control sequences without `_` are designed in "user naming space". Thus: if @Azagal258 used OpTeX then no problem would be after `\def\par{...}`.

Comment: @wipet `\par` has been non-primitve (at times) in latex since the start, it is the case more often now, but as you know the error here is unrelated to the definition of `\par` it is a primitive property of the cstoken with name `par` whatver its definition.

Comment: @wipet are you saying you also stop a blank line returning `\par`? I doubt the OP wants blank lines to generate partial derivative fractions

Comment: @wipet ah you do, nice:-) luatex.... :-)

Comment: @wipet  `others.opm`: `Lua\TeX/ version 1.14 and newer provides \`\partokenname\` which allows to    specify something different than \`\par\` at empty lines.` wasn't that your suggestion originally?

Comment: Yes, It was my suggestion and my implementation for pdfTeX and XeTeX using a change file.

Comment: @wipet It works well for this, I see.